# How can I change the login status of my Prestashop navigation bar? (Login/Logout button)

Tags: authentication, navigation, prestashop

I am currently working with Prestashop right now, I have a modified skin but I found out my Login button does not change from "Login" to "Logout" if I'm not signed in. Now I tried to dig through the hierarchy to look up where the name is defined, but could not find it. To view a live preview of my website you can visit
[this link](http://www.jorritpresta.microdesign.nl).

If anyone could tell me how I can edit the navigation menu, or better yet the login status of my navigation button, that would really help me along. Thanks for the assistance :).

Greetings J.I.N.

Answer (score 1):

It may depends on the Prestashop version and the module you are using, but with the `blockuserinfo` module it works like this (in Prestashop 1.5):

```
{if $logged}
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('index', true, NULL, 'mylogout')}">{l s='Log out' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
{else}
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)}">{l s='Login' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: I am getting same problem with the version 1.6.1.2   , any solution? @romainberfer